# How to properly optimize event handlers in react

Tags: reactjs

I think I went a bit too far into trying to optmize my react (native) components and I want to ask the community here for an opinion.

Have a look at this simple component where I'm trying to implement a simple tab navigation:

```
const NavigationTabs: React.FC = () => {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();

  const handleNavigate = (screen: string) => () =>
    navigate(screen);
    
  return (
    <TabWrapper>
      <Tab onPress={handleNavigate("Screen1")}>
        <Label>Screen 1</Label>
      </Tab>
      <Tab onPress={handleNavigate("Screen2")}>
        <Label>Screen 2</Label>
      </Tab>
    </TabWrapper>
  );
};
```

I'm using an higher order function, `handleNavigate` to handle the navigation to different screens (instead of defining N navigation functions where N is the number of screens I need to link the app to) that everytime returns a new function. Now I want to memoize the function returned by `handleNavigate` so that the function passed down to the Tab component is always the same, do you think this is this a good way of doing it?

```
  const handleNavigate = React.useCallback(
    (screen: string) => () =>
      navigate(screen),
    []
  );
```

Comment: I don't see why you're using a higher-order function for this - why can't you call `navigate(screen)` directly from the `onPress` using the same string-literals? (I'm not familiar with React Native so I don't know if using a higher-order function here is idiomatic or not)

Comment: Additionally, your `useCallback` call-site isn't passing any dependencies in the array argument - it's just an empty array, so the memoized callback will never be invalidated (...I think, if I'm understanding React's documentation correctly)

Comment: if I use `onPress={() => navigate(screen)}` Everytime the NavigationTabs component renders it will also trigger a new render on every tab because I'm passing a new function

Comment: useCallback doesn't have any dependency in this case, I want the function returned by useCallback memoized only once

Comment: anyway I'm looking for opinions about it, I found clear explainations of useCallback with first order functions, but I wasn't able to find relevant stuff on an implementation like mine and I'm wondering why, maybe it's garbage? :)

Comment: I've been reading the React documentation, and I believe you **can** use the `onPress={() => navigate("Screen1")}` approach, but you need to move your JSX into your component's `render()` function instead of using the single-function-does-everything approach. See here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html - I don't know if things are different in React Native though. The same expressions are used in https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html as well. But as I said, I'm not a React / React Native user so I could be (and probably am) wrong :)